# Parse a custom log file in python

Tags: python, logparser

I have a log file with new line character

Sample File:

```
2019-02-12T00:01:03.428+01:00 [Error] ErrorCode {My error: "A"} -  -  - 00000000-0000-0000-6936-008007000000 
2019-02-12T00:01:03.428+01:00 [Error] ErrorCode {My error: "A"} -  -  - 00000000-0000-0000-6936-008007000000 
2019-02-12T00:03:23.944+01:00 [Information] A validation warning occurred: [[]] while running a file,
--- End of stack trace ---
    FileNotFoundError
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System Error
```

I want to split the data in three columns namely Timestamp, type_code to show whether the event is an error, warning or information and then the message.

I have used split function for this:

```
currentDict = {"date":line.split("] ")[0].split(" [")[0],
                   "type":line.split("] ")[0].split(" [")[1],"text":line.split(" ]")[0].split("] ")[1]}
```

To split the data in the given columns it works fine but gives error if i have a entry shown below

```
2019-02-12T00:03:23.944+01:00 [Information] A validation warning occurred: [[]] while running a file,
--- End of stack trace ---
    FileNotFoundError
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System Error
```

and second approach is using regex

```
with open(name, "r") as f:
         for lines in f:
             data_matcher = re.findall("^\\d{4}[-]?\\d{1,2}[-]?\\d{1,2}T\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}.\\d{1,3}[+]?\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}",
                              lines)
```

[image: Expected Output]

using this i am only able to extract the timestamp but stuck as to how to extract the next to fields.

Comment: Well, how to say it best: using spaces as field divider and inside of the field without being quoted at the same time will be a serious problem in parsing this. You could try a limited left split and a then a limited right split to near the text field from both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be that precise with your regex:

```py
import re

log_pattern = re.compile(r"([0-9\-]*)T([0-9\-:.+]*)\s*\[([^]]*)\](.*)")

with open(name, "r") as f:
  for line in f:
      match = log_pattern.match(line)
      if not match:
        continue
      grps = match.groups()
      print("Log line:")
      print(f"  date:{grps[0]},\n  time:{grps[1]},\n  type:{grps[2]},\n  text:{grps[3]}")
```

You could even imagine being less precise than that, for example `r"(.*)T([^\s]*)\s*\[([^]]*)\](.*)"` works too. Here is a nice tool to use to test regular expressions: [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 2):

A good piece of advice when parsing is to **stop trying to do things in one shot** (even though it is fun). For example, writing a big regex to parse everything:

```
re.findall("...", TEXT)
```

Or extracting a value from a piece of text in a single (sometimes chained) line of code:

```
LINE.split("...")[...].split("...")[...]
```

Instead, decompose the logic into a **sequence of easy steps** (typically with assignment to intermediate variables), where each step prepares the way for another easy step. In your case, those steps might be:

```
time, rest = line.split(' [', 1)
line_type, msg = rest.split('] ', 1)
```

And in the real world of messy data, you sometimes need to add error-handling or sanity-checking logic in between the small steps.