# Parse a custom log file into a dictionary using regex

Tags: python, regex

Sample log file

```
Jun 15 02:04:59 combo sshd(pam_unix)[20897]: authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=NODEVssh ruser= rhost=220-135-151-1.hinet-ip.hinet.net  user=root\n'
Jun 15 02:04:59 combo sshd(pam_unix)[20898]: authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=NODEVssh ruser= rhost=220-135-151-1.hinet-ip.hinet.net  user=root\n'
Jun 15 04:06:18 combo su(pam_unix)[21416]: session opened for user cyrus by (uid=0)\n'
Jun 15 04:06:19 combo su(pam_unix)[21416]: session closed for user cyrus\n'
Jun 15 04:06:20 combo logrotate: ALERT exited abnormally with [1]\n'
Jun 15 04:12:42 combo su(pam_unix)[22644]: session opened for user news by (uid=0)\n'
Jun 15 04:12:43 combo su(pam_unix)[22644]: session closed for user news\n'
```

I want to split the data into 4 columns, Date, Time, PID and the Message.

Sample output would be

```
Dict = {"Date": "Jun 15", "Time": "02:04:59", "PID": "20897", "Message": "authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=NODEVssh ruser= rhost=220-135-151-1.hinet-ip.hinet.net  user=root\n'"}
```

After which I intend to save this info into a CSV file based on the columns

I've tried looking at other examples such as:

[Parse a custom log file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283923/parse-a-custom-log-file-in-python)

[How to parse this custom log file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627810/how-to-parse-this-custom-log-file-in-python)

but I do not know how to create capture groups to help me achieve this.

The current Regex I have are

"(\w{3} \d{2})" for the Date

"(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})" for time

"(?<=[).+?(?=]:)" for PID

"((?<=:).*)" for Message

but nothing happens when i combine them together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to iterate over each row. For each row, select the `Date`, `Time`, `PID` and `Message` using a specific regex.

If they are found, return the value. Else, return `None`.

Here the code:

```
# Import module
import re

# Output list
out = []
# Read file
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    # Iterate over all lines
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Select the different fields
        date = re.search(r'^(\w{3}\s\d{2})', line)
        time = re.search(r'(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', line)
        PID = re.search(r'\[([0-9]+)\]:', line)
        message = re.search(r":\s(.*?)$", line)
        # Append them to the output using a dict
        # If field isn't found, None is return
        out.append({
            "Date": date.group(1) if date else None,
            "Time": time.group(1) if time else None,
            "PID": PID.group(1) if PID else None,
            "Message": message.group(1) if message else None
        })
```

*output*:

```
# [
#     {'Date': 'Jun 15', 'Time': '02:04:59', 'PID': '20897', 'Message': "authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=NODEVssh ruser= rhost=220-135-151-1.hinet-ip.hinet.net  user=root\\n'"},
#     {'Date': 'Jun 15', 'Time': '02:04:59', 'PID': '20898', 'Message': "authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=NODEVssh ruser= rhost=220-135-151-1.hinet-ip.hinet.net  user=root\\n'"},
#     {'Date': 'Jun 15', 'Time': '04:06:18', 'PID': '21416', 'Message': "session opened for user cyrus by (uid=0)\\n'"},
#     {'Date': 'Jun 15', 'Time': '04:06:19', 'PID': '21416', 'Message': "session closed for user cyrus\\n'"},
#     {'Date': 'Jun 15', 'Time': '04:06:20', 'PID': None, 'Message': "ALERT exited abnormally with [1]\\n'"},
#     {'Date': 'Jun 15', 'Time': '04:12:42', 'PID': '22644', 'Message': "session opened for user news by (uid=0)\\n'"},
#     {'Date': 'Jun 15', 'Time': '04:12:43', 'PID': '22644', 'Message': 'session closed for user news\\n'}
# ]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I doubt OP needs to find multiple occurrences of each pattern on each line. `re.search` must be a better bet here, and then there will be a single regex call per line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're right, `re.search` is more appropriate. Thank's for feedback :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to checkout the [logs_to_df](https://advertools.readthedocs.io/en/master/advertools.logs.html) function from `advertools`. It parses any log format, and compresses the resulting file using the parquet format.

There are default formats supported, but if you have a custom format, you only need to provide a regex, and field names:

```py
import advertools as adv
import pandas as pd

adv.logs_to_df(log_file='log_file.log',
               output_file='log_file.parquet',
               errors_file='log_file.txt',
               log_format=r'([A-Z][a-z]{2} \d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d) combo ([a-z]+\([a-z_]+?\))\[(\d+)\]: (.*)',
               fields=['datetime', 'program', 'pid', 'message'])

log_df = pd.read_parquet('log_file.parquet')
log_df
```

|  | datetime | program | pid | message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jun 15 02:04:59 | sshd(pam_unix) | 20897 | authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=NODEVssh ruser= rhost=220-135-151-1.hinet-ip.hinet.net user=root\n' |
| 1 | Jun 15 02:04:59 | sshd(pam_unix) | 20898 | authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=NODEVssh ruser= rhost=220-135-151-1.hinet-ip.hinet.net user=root\n' |
| 2 | Jun 15 04:06:18 | su(pam_unix) | 21416 | session opened for user cyrus by (uid=0)\n' |
| 3 | Jun 15 04:06:19 | su(pam_unix) | 21416 | session closed for user cyrus\n' |
| 4 | Jun 15 04:12:42 | su(pam_unix) | 22644 | session opened for user news by (uid=0)\n' |
| 5 | Jun 15 04:12:43 | su(pam_unix) | 22644 | session closed for user news\n' |

Note that the line containing "logrotate" wasn't included in the output file, but would be included in the `errors_file`, so you can further parse those, or check if there are actually issues with them.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean combine them together? Have you tried doing it in a for loop? That's probably that way I would go about doing it. It sounds like you are trying to capture all groups and passing them to the `re.findall` (I'm guessing). But findall is used to capture multiple instances of a single capture group. Hence, put your regex in a list, iterate and match each one using `re.find` or the `captures` method. The regex you have is correct (though for the date, I would capture the first two words of each line).

Comment: From the other example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283923/parse-a-custom-log-file-in-python), they had a very long regex pattern that can capture multiple groups

Comment: So you would rather use a foreign method and more obfuscated regex to achieve the same goal that can be done using simple syntax? That is against the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) but I'm curious, is this a need?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately i need to use regex to do this as its a requirement for my assignment

Comment: Let me clarify; are you not allowed to use a for loop or do you just want an elegant solution? I will explore and get back to you.

Comment: I can use a loop but i just need to use regex to extract the data into the 4 columns