# Log errors from logs.txt file to another file, exceptions.txt

Tags: python, error-logging

I am currently trying to log the errors only from logs.txt file to exceptions.txt file using python in VSCode. All three files, i.e., logs.txt, exceptions.txt and log_parser.py, on which I am writing the parser code are present in the same folder which I have opened on VS code. I have various multiline  exceptions on the logs.txt file and some single line exceptions which I need to log in the exceptions.txt file in a way that is-
error no. exception type: __
Timestamp:__
Details:__
I also don't want any repetitions in exceptions.txt file. Should I use word embeddings for the same? What should my approach be here?

Right now, I have tried a simple code which could just log errors, but it is not showing up on exceptions.txt, can you help me fix this and suggest what to do for next steps?

here is my code:

```
import logging
import sys



# Create a custom StreamHandler to redirect logs to both console and file

class MultiStreamHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
def __init__(self, streams):
super().__init__()
self.streams = streams

    def emit(self, record):
        for stream in self.streams:
            stream.write(self.format(record) + self.terminator)

# Configure logging to write to console and file

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('path\\exceptions.txt', mode='w')
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
multi_handler = MultiStreamHandler(\[file_handler.stream, console_handler.stream\])
logger.addHandler(multi_handler)

def parse_logs(logs_file, exceptions_file):
with open(logs_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
error_lines = \[\]  # Stores the lines of a multiline error
error_number = 0
for line in file:
line = line.strip().lower()
if line.startswith('e '):  # Only process lines starting with 'E'
if 'at' not in line:
if error_lines:
logger.error('\\n'.join(error_lines))
error_lines = \[\]
error_number += 1
logger.error(f'Error {error_number}: {line}')
else:
error_lines.append(line)

        # Check if there are any remaining error lines after processing the file
        if error_lines:
            logger.error('\n'.join(error_lines))

try:
logs_file_path = r'path\\logs.txt'
exceptions_file_path = r'path\\exceptions.txt'

    parse_logs(logs_file_path, exceptions_file_path)
    
    print("Script execution completed.")

except Exception as err:
logger.exception("An error occurred during script execution.")
```

I have written the code now with loguru and it can only log single line error, help me with this for logging in multiline exceptions, thanks!

```
from loguru import logger
import re

logger.add("exceptions.txt", format="{message}", level="ERROR")

def log_exceptions():
    with open("logs.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        logs = file.read()

    pattern = r"\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}.*? E (.*?): (.*?)(?=\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}.*? E .*?:|$)"
    errors = re.finditer(pattern, logs, flags=re.DOTALL)

    error_set = set()
    error_number = 1
    multiline_exception = False
    multiline_exception_type = ""
    multiline_exception_details = ""

    for match in errors:
        exception_line = match.group(1).strip()
        exception_details = match.group(2).strip()

        if multiline_exception:
            if exception_line.startswith("java.lang.") or exception_line.startswith("at "):
                multiline_exception_details += f"\n{exception_line}"
            else:
                logger.error(f"{error_number}. {multiline_exception_type}")
                logger.error(f"Exception Type: {multiline_exception_type}")
                logger.error(f"Details:\n{multiline_exception_details}")
                error_set.add(multiline_exception_details)
                error_number += 1
                multiline_exception = False

        exception_type_match = re.search(r"java\.lang\.(.*?)\b", exception_line)
        if exception_type_match:
            exception_type = exception_type_match.group(1)
            multiline_exception = True
            multiline_exception_type = exception_type
            multiline_exception_details = exception_details
        else:
            exception_type = exception_line.split(".")[-1]

            if exception_details not in error_set:
                logger.error(f"{error_number}. {exception_type}")
                logger.error(f"Exception Type: {exception_type}")
                logger.error(f"Details:\n{exception_details}")
                error_set.add(exception_details)
                error_number += 1

    # Additional handling for the last multi-line exception in the logs
    if multiline_exception:
        logger.error(f"{error_number}. {multiline_exception_type}")
        logger.error(f"Exception Type: {multiline_exception_type}")
        logger.error(f"Details:\n{multiline_exception_details}")

# Usage
log_exceptions()
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse an already existing log file "log.txt". I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish. Do you need to log your python code or you want to parse an existing text file?

Comment: @SamuelO.D. I want to log exceptions in another .txt file from an already existing logs.txt file, which is generated from an android apk. writing parser in python

Comment: Okey that's a completely different problem. You shouldn't use the logging package or loguru for this task. The logging is already done (in your Android app). Now you need to write a parser for your text file. For this I recommend you take a look at the "re" package, which lets you use regex to process your text.

Answer (score 0):

**New answer**

The problem you are describing is not a logging task, but a parsing one. If you already have logs in a text file, you just need to process the text file.

For this task, as you have multiline exceptions, you should use the "re" package and build a regular expression (regex) that matches the syntax of your exceptions.

[Check this answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55284313/7257731)

---

**Old answer** (edited because it answers a different question).

You should try loguru. This library lets you do a lot of things with logs very easily.

Configure logger:

```
from loguru import logger

# Remove default logger (optional, by default the default logger outputs everything to the console)
logger.remove()    

# Set default logger for logs.txt
logger.add("logs.txt", level="DEBUG")

# Set logger for errors
logger.add("exceptions.txt", level="ERROR")
```

[Check the library docs](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/logger.html) and the [quick start guide](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru). There is a lot of format and file customization available (file rotation, log format...)

Use logger:

```
# Log basic messages
logger.debug("Message for developer")
logger.info("Message for user")
logger.success("Log sucessfull result")

# Log important messages
logger.warning("Warning message")  # With the current configuration, this will only show in logs.txt
logger.error("Descriptive error message")  # This doesn't record the error trace

# Log exceptions
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception(e)  # This will send the whole trace to logs.txt and exceptions.txt
```

Comment: Hi, I implemented this but it can only log for single line exception, not multiline, how to fix that?
I have added my code above.